# Datatables Ajax Data: Send Json Array to ASP.NET Controller

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to send data in a json array to an ASP.NET Controller. I'm able to send the data to the controller perfectly using jQuery Ajax, but unable to do the same using Datatables.net Ajax.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DataTablesHandler(DTParameters param, List<AdvancedSearch> advSearch)
{
    //code...
}
```

Datatables:

```
var dt = table.DataTable({
        columns: [],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Controller/DataTablesHandler',
            data: function (d)
            {
                d.advSearch = advSearch;
            }
        }
    });
```

Json Array:

```
advSearch = [{"column":"id","value":"1"},{"column":"name","value":"Jon Snow"}];
```

The controllers advSearch list parameter is always empty. 
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i was unable to send a List object to my Controller, i ended up sending the data as a string and parsing the values in the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DataTablesHandler(DTParameters param, string advSearch)
{
     ///convert JSON string to List<AdvancedSearch>
     var advSearchParams = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AdvancedSearch>>(advSearch);

     //(...)
}
```